# Changing yes/no value in database, on click of hyperlink

Tags: javascript, php, html, checkbox

sorry about my limited coding skills and so on, but hopefully you can see what I am attempting. I want to scrap the form checkboxes and have 2 simple 'yes' 'no' hyperlinks, dependant on if image is hidden or shown. Will javascript do this? This is what I have so far, which was working but like I say, I just want 2 links instead of checkboxes.

```
if ($_POST['option']) {    

    if ($_POST['option'] == 'yes') {$hidden = 0;}
    if ($_POST['option'] == 'no') {$hidden = 1;}

@mysql_query('UPDATE Image SET Hidden = ‘.$hidden.’ WHERE ID = '.$image->ID.'');

        header ('Location: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
            exit;    
            }

<p>Show image? 
        <form method="post" action="?">
<input type="checkbox" name="option" value="yes">Yes 
<input type="checkbox" name="option" value="no" >No 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go!" /> 
        </form>
```

So then I can have HTML such as  -
**Show Image? Yes / No
(This image is shown) or (this image is not shown)**

### Any points in the right direction would be greatly appreciated, Many thanks!

Hi Guys, Sorry, I don’t think I explained myself properly.
All images have a default value of ‘Hidden = 0’  in the image database table, so they are all currently shown on the page. Here is the code -

```
// there is  some SQL here that fetches all images
// here is the actual code that shows images:

foreach($ids as $id)
    {
    $tmp = new Image($id,true);
    if (!$tmp->ID) continue;
<p>
<img src=”/myurl/’.$tmp->ID.’.jpg”>
</p>
}
```

What I want is, in that loop, underneath each image tag, is to have some HTML :

```
<p>Show Image? Yes / No </p>
```

I want the ‘yes’ and ‘no’ to be hyperlinks, which state will depend on the images ‘Hidden’ value. 
So if the image is shown (all currently are), the word ‘Yes’ won’t be a clickable hyperlink, only ‘No’ will be.
If I then click ‘No’ I need it to post a query on click, to set Hidden = 1, to hide the image. 
If the image is already hidden, then ‘Yes’ would be the only clickable link, which if clicked would post value Hidden = 0, so the image is shown.

I hope that makes sense. The other problem I have is the fact that there are multiple images, so the form or whatever system I use, needs to distinguish which image it is changing the Hidden value for. 
In the code, the image’s unique id field is accessed like this: $tmp->ID

Comment: Can you further elaborate on this?

Comment: A little confused on what you're trying to ask here. Are you just trying to change the value of yes/no inside the database depending on which hyperlink is clicked?

Comment: Hi, sorry. I hopefully have explained it better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want hyperlinks just use something like

```
<a href="myphpfile.php?option=yes">Yes</a>
<a href="myphpfile.php?option=no">No</a>
```

Also you will probably want to use single quotes `'`'s and not `‘`'s for your query. Also I'd recommend using `mysqli` or `PDO` so you can use prepared statements instead of `mysql_` functions which are prone to mysql injections.

Comment: Thanks, this is the sort of thing I wanted, but for some reason it won't work. The url system of my site throws me to the edit image page as soon as i click one of the yes/no links

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(isset($_GET['cmd']))
{
    if($_GET['cmd']=='yes')
    {$hidden = 0;}
    if($_GET['cmd']=='no')
    {$hidden = 1;}

@mysql_query('UPDATE Image SET Hidden = '.$hidden.' WHERE ID = '.$image->ID.'');

        header ('Location: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
            exit;    
           }

?>
<p>Show image? <br />
      <a href="yesNoLink.php?cmd=yes">Yes</a> <br /> <!--Replace page url according to yours -->
      <a href="yesNoLink.php?cmd=no">No</a>
```

Comment: I followed this example exactly, except my links are like this -
<a href="'.$user->URL.'/pictures/'.$this->Entity->URL.'/'.$tmp->ID.'?cmd=yes">Yes</a>

the site didnt like it and sent me to another page

Comment: Yes/No links part is in html, did you enclose the url part within <?php ?> tags while printing them?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to use a hidden input field that will be submitted with the rest of your form and using javascript to change the value of that hidden field.

HTML:

```
 <p>Show image? 
            <form method="post" action="?">
    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="default" />

    <a href="#" class="option" data-value="yes">Yes</a>
    <a href="#" class="option" data-value="no">No</a>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go!" /> 
            </form>
```

JS (requires JQuery):

```
$(".option").click(function (e) {

    $("input[name=option]").val($(this).attr("data-value"));

});
```

Then when you submit the form `$_POST` should have the "option" value.

Answer (score 0):

Just to reaffirm, the following form is my latest revision and works perfectly, updating the database and radio buttons on the page. However, it is still not the solution I want. I want hyperlinks only, as in the above examples posted by Boshi and Class, but for some reason my site won't accept those urls, the system churns me out to a different page and nothing works.
Here is the latest revision which works. Is there another solution? -

```
if ($_POST[''.$tmp->ID.'']) {    

    if ($_POST[''.$tmp->ID.''] == 'yes') {$hidden = 1;}
    if ($_POST[''.$tmp->ID.''] == 'no') {$hidden = 0;}

@mysql_query('UPDATE Image SET Hidden = '.$hidden.' WHERE ID = '.$tmp->ID.' LIMIT 1');

        header ('Location: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
            exit;    
            }

        <p>Hide image? 
        <form method="post" action="?">
<input type="radio" name="'.$tmp->ID.'" value="yes" '.($tmp->Hidden ? 'checked' : '').'>Yes 
<input type="radio" name="'.$tmp->ID.'" value="no" '.(!$tmp->Hidden ? 'checked' : '').'>No 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go!" /> 
        </form>
```